# Is there a way to know if the reject function of a Promise has been handled?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a simple Promise that I execute:

```
function handleCall(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        xhr.get(url).then(
            resolve,
            err => {
                if (!reject(err)) {
                    // Handle here the error in a generic way
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

The idea here is to let me handle the error when I want, by adding a `.catch` to the `handleCall` method, but if there is no catch mechanism, the `handleCall` would fall back to the default actions defined in that function.

Of course, my above code doesn't work, the `reject` function returns null even if my custom catch returns something.

I tried with a try/catch block instead, in the idea that "if no catch method is defined when calling, then an exception might be thrown", but it's not working either.

Is there a way to achieve this? I mean, letting the caller of `handleCall` handle the error, but if no error has been implemented (no catch), then fallback to the generic one on `handleCall`?

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743)

Comment: You can't know that. The consumer calling `.then` and/or `.catch` on your promise is creating _new_ promises, based on the source. You might as well just `return xhr.get(url);` and not create the `new Promise` at all.